# Throwing PXSetPropertyException on a lookup field shows ID only

Tags: acumatica

When I throw an error in the FieldVerifying or FieldUpdating event handler for a grid field that’s a lookup field, it’s showing only the ID of the lookup value in red instead of the description.

[image: Error field]

The error throw is pretty simple (see below). TField is an IBqlField supplied via generic to my method.

```
throw new PXSetPropertyException<TField>(Message.WarehouseDoesntMatchShipTo, PXErrorLevel.Error);
```

Is there a way to get it to show the description in red instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the new value to the warehouse CD string value before throwing the exception. Requires a query to INSite in your example.

If you want the old warehouse CD value (value before user tried to change) just change the value used in the PXSelect to row.SiteID

```
protected virtual void SOLine_SiteID_FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (SOLine)e.Row;
    if (row == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    INSite inSite = PXSelect<INSite, Where<INSite.siteID, Equal<Required<INSite.siteID>>>>.Select(this, e.NewValue);
    e.NewValue = inSite?.SiteCD;
    throw new PXSetPropertyException($"Invalid Warehouse {inSite?.SiteCD}", PXErrorLevel.Error);
}
```